# Return string from C function accepting two strings

Tags: c, compiler-errors

Forgive my C newbness!  I'm trying to create a function that accepts two char arrays as arguments, and returns some JSON.  Here is my code, followed by compile warnings.  The program simply segfaults upon execution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)
{
        char *json;
        json = malloc(strlen(obuf)+37);
        strcpy(json, "{\"sessionline\":{\"sid\":\"");
        strcat(json, sid);
        strcat(json, "\",\"line\":\"");
        strcat(json, obuf);
        strcat(json, "\"}}");
        return json;
}

int main()
{
        char *sid = "xyzxyzxyz";
        char *obuf = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
        char *json = get_json(sid, obuf);
        printf(json);
}
```

When compiling with gcc:

```
test.c: In function ‘get_json’:
test.c:14:9: warning: return makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]
         return json;
         ^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:21:22: warning: initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
         char *json = get_json(sid, obuf);
                      ^
test.c:22:9: warning: format not a string literal and no format arguments [-Wformat-security]
         printf(json);
         ^
```

Comment: You forgot `*` in function return type.

Comment: You can simplify all these functions by using sprintf()

Comment: Looks like a typo.  `char get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)` should be `char* get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)`.  note the `*` on the return type.

Comment: I could not bother to count the lengths of the string literals, but you *do* remember to allocate enough memory to fit the string terminator? And you should also free the memory you allocate somewhere.

Comment: Thanks NathanOliver, that worked perfectly!

Comment: Not a typo however, but a beginner mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are returning a char* as a char.

Your function declaration should look like this:

```
char* get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)
```

You also seem to put more stuff into `json` than it can fit given its size.

The segfault happens because in the conversion from `char*` to `char` the number is truncated to 1B, so `printf(json)` tries to read some byte of memory between 0 - 255, which it did not reserve previously.

Comment: Typo questions should be closed.  You should vote/flag for closing instead of answering.

Comment: Doesn't this line allocate both *sid and *obuf lengths to the json variable?  json = malloc(strlen(sid)+strlen(obuf)+37);  The 37 is the rest of the static json - sid and obuf would be dynamic sizes.

Comment: @Cotton yes it does, but in your question you used the line `malloc(strlen(obuf)+37)`

Answer (score 1):

- `get_json` should return a pointer `char*`, not `char`.
- You forgot to include `sid` to the length to allocate, so your program will cause out-of-range access and invoke *undefined behavior*.
- There are no harm in *this* program, but generally putting string from user into the format string of `printf()` is dangerous.

Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)
{
        char *json;
        json = malloc(strlen(sid)+strlen(obuf)+37);
        if(json == NULL) return json;
        strcpy(json, "{\"sessionline\":{\"sid\":\"");
        strcat(json, sid);
        strcat(json, "\",\"line\":\"");
        strcat(json, obuf);
        strcat(json, "\"}}");
        return json;
}

int main(void)
{
        char *sid = "xyzxyzxyz";
        char *obuf = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
        char *json = get_json(sid, obuf);
        if (json != NULL) fputs(json, stdout);
}
```

or simpler this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char get_json(char *sid, char *obuf)
{
        char *json;
        json = malloc(strlen(sid)+strlen(obuf)+37);
        if(json == NULL) return json;
        sprintf(json, "{\"sessionline\":{\"sid\":\""
                "%s"
                "\",\"line\":\""
                "%s"
                "\"}}", sid, obuf);
        return json;
}

int main(void)
{
        char *sid = "xyzxyzxyz";
        char *obuf = "asdfasdfasdfasdf";
        char *json = get_json(sid, obuf);
        if(json != NULL) fputs(json, stdout);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the additional tips.